# Cookie Expiration - How is chrome and edge miscalculating the cookie expiration date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, windows-server-2016

On a Microsoft Server 2016 - we are creating a Http response cookie that expires in 20 minutes.

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

In the chrome browser (Version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)) the time is only 14 minutes ahead.
2022-12-22T19:48:26.705Z

Whereas firefox will have the correct time 22 DEC 2022 19:54:08 GMT

The time on the server is correct. When the cookie appears in the browser the time is incorrect.  Not sure what all to check.  One other fact was it was working just fine until Monday of this week.  So I extended the expiration time to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Check your clocks on both server and client. Use a website like https://time.is/
for this purpose.

Comment: They are both in sync.

Comment: Wow, absolutely no clue what is going on. The 14 minutes makes no sense....